# Why can't I join Minecraft PE worlds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, hosting

I have an android phone and my sister has a Kindle fire.

When we play with our friends ( who both have kindles ) I can join their worlds and vise-versa.

But when I try to join my sisters worlds on her kindle I can't. She can join my worlds on my phone but I can't join hers on her kindle fire.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? And if so what is it?

Answer (score -1):

Go to options and turn on local multiplayer